# Option in hg review or hg postreview when updating an existing review to prevent from publishing the review

Tags: mercurial

I have used Perforce with reviewboard and postreview on an existing review wouldn't publish the review automatically. Instead, it created a draft which I could then open in a web browser, update the review with a change description and then publish(i.e. make available to my reviewers)

I couldn't find a way that the same thing can be achieved with mercurial. It seems like mercurial's default setting is to publish as soon as you say:
hg review -e  
Only when creating a new review does it create a draft.

Is this a setting that can be modified?

Comment: `hg review` is not in core mercurial... what extension does provide that?

Comment: Seems reviewboard. Random suggestions: Maybe the default setting for new commits plays a role. Alternatively try to change the repository itself to a non-publishing one

Comment: Yes it is linked with reviewboard. Is there a way to change the default setting for new commits? I will try and look some more at your second suggestion.

Comment: Ever since mercurial gained phases, you can set the default phase for commits in your .hgrc: `[phases]\n new-commit = draft`

Comment: But if you are updating the same changeset by using hg histedit (and fold), it will not recognize it as a new commit right?

Comment: Yes, but every change by whatever tool to a changeset will make it a new commit (i.e. alter its hash). But if you use a mechanism like evolve (and I don't know how review extension does it, likely similar), then mercurial will use obsolescence markers and thus know which (new) changeset replaces the old one and it will hide the old one by default.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try the suggested change to .hgrc. Appreciate your responses.